# Question about sufficiency

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics, conditioning

I learned in my (classical) statistics class that (if we have densities) $T(X)$ is sufficient iff $$f(x)= g(T(x))h(x)$$

I am reading "[the Bayesian Choice](https://amzn.to/2kxykkw)" and there the factorization-lemma is quoted as $T(X)$ being sufficient if $$f(x|\theta)=g(T(x)|\theta)\cdot h(x|T(x))$$

I am slightly confused, why isn`t it

$$f(x|\theta)=g(T(x)|\theta)\cdot h(x)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the question (and reading [the Bayesian Choice](http://amzn.to/2kxykkw)!). If you consider both equations
$$f(x)= g(T(x))h(x)\qquad\qquad(1)$$
and
$$f(x|\theta)=g(T(x)|\theta)\cdot h(x|T(x))\qquad\qquad(2)$$
they are not that dissimilar, once the dependence on the parameter $\theta$ is taken into account. Actually, (1) is not meaningful for sufficiency if the densities $f$ and $g$ are not indexed by a parameter. Sufficiency then corresponds to $h$ *not* being indexed by this parameter.

This remark being made, (2) appears as a special case of (2), where
$$h(x)=h(x|T(x))$$
The additional conditioning expresses in an informal manner that the density of $X$ is proportional to the joint density of $(X,T(X)$, which can be written as the marginal density of $T(X)$, $g(t|\theta)$, times the conditional density of $X$ given $T(X)$, $h(x|T(x))$. This is informal as one needs to define proper dominating measures and the like.

Comment: I was puzzled why h is conditioned on T. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I wonder whether it is possible to get a solution manual for the Bayesian choice?

Comment: There are rogue solution manuals for the BC available somewhere on the Web, but no official version as a subset of solutions is made available for instructors via Springer...